# Rejoin sequential record rows in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, transformation, data-manipulation

I'm working with a dataset where the record rows have been split up into two.

The data I'm working with currently looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  row_id = 1:10,
  V1 = c("burger", "01-01-2016", "chicken patty", "01-02-2016", "veggie burger", "01-03-2016", "turkey burger", "01-01-2016", "veggie burger", "01-02-2016"), 
  V2 = c("cheese", "very tasty", "onions", "ok", NA, "tasty", "cheese", "ok", "onions", NA),
  V3 = c("bun", NA, "wrap", NA, "bun", NA, "wrap", NA, NA, NA)
)


    row_id            V1               V2           V3
      1              burger          cheese         bun
      2              01-01-2016      very tasty     NA
      3              chicken patty   onions         wrap    
      4              01-02-2016      ok             NA
      5              veggie burger   NA             bun
      6              01-03-2016      tasty          NA
      7              turkey burger   cheese         wrap
      8              01-01-2016      ok             NA
      9              veggie burger   onions         NA
      10             01-02-2016      NA             NA
```

However, I need to bring back together the appropriate record rows, 
and have my data look like this:

```
    row_id            V1               V2           V3          V4            V5
      1              burger          cheese         bun       01-01-2016      very tasty
      2              chicken patty   onions         wrap      01-02-2016      ok
      3              veggie burger   NA             bun       01-03-2016      tasty
      4              turkey burger   cheese         wrap      01-01-2016      ok
      5              veggie burger   onions         NA        01-02-2016      NA
```

I've thought of perhaps doing something where I append the proceeding row. However, I do not know how I would go about writing such a process.

I'm currently using the dplyr library, so any response posted using dplyr would be extra helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `cbind()` the even and uneven rows and drop irrelevant columns:

```
cbind(df[c(TRUE, FALSE), -1], df[c(FALSE, TRUE), -c(1, 4)])
             V1     V2   V3         V1         V2
1        burger cheese  bun 01-01-2016 very tasty
3 chicken patty onions wrap 01-02-2016         ok
5 veggie burger   <NA>  bun 01-03-2016      tasty
7 turkey burger cheese wrap 01-01-2016         ok
9 veggie burger onions <NA> 01-02-2016       <NA>
```